# how to know specification and implementation at node of ES Modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm confused about ES Modules system.

I usually using import/export syntax on babel, 
but i don't know what state the ES Modules spec in ECMA script spec & pure node implementation.

1. Where is the description of ES Modules in ECMA 262 spec?
2. How can i know is ES Modules feature enable in specific node.js version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the description of ES Modules in ECMA 262 spec?

on their [Official Page](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for this spec:

ECMA-262 edition 8 > ECMAScript Language: Scripts and Modules > Modules

> How can i know is ES Modules feature enable in specific node.js version?

1. go to google
2. search for "nodejs ES6 modules"
3. click the first result

and you end up here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html